# ¿Cómo puedo cubrir todas las posibilidad de este código? - Paridad de Paréntesis ( [ { -

Tags: java

Se me pidió desarrollar una aplicación que verificara la paridad de distintos paréntesis: ([{
y realice el siguiente código;

public boolean verificarParidad(String array){

```
    Deque<Character> evaluarParentesis = new ArrayDeque<>(); // array deque de caracteres 
    boolean resultado = true; 
    int coontadorAbiertos = 0; 
    int coontadorCerrados = 0; 
    
    // VERIFICAMOS LOS CASOS MAS OBVIOS DE ERROR
    if(array.charAt(array.length()) == '(' || array.charAt(array.length()) == '[' || array.charAt(array.length()) == '{' ){ // si el array termine con abierto 
        resultado = false; // NO 
    }else if(array.charAt(0) == ')' || array.charAt(0) == ']' || array.charAt(0) == '}' ){ // si el array empieza con cerrado
        resultado = false; // NO
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            if(array.charAt(i) == '(' || array.charAt(i) == '[' || array.charAt(i) == '{'){
                coontadorAbiertos ++; 
            }else if(array.charAt(i) == ')' || array.charAt(i) == ']' || array.charAt(i) == '}'){
                coontadorCerrados ++; 
            }
        }
        if(coontadorAbiertos != coontadorCerrados){
            resultado = false; // NO 
        }else{
            // VERIFICAMOS LOS CASOS EXTRA 
             for(int a = 0; a < array.length(); a ++){ // recorrer el tamaño de la cadena
                if(array.charAt(a) == '(' || array.charAt(a) == '[' || array.charAt(a) == '{'){ // si el parentesis es abierto 
                     evaluarParentesis.push(array.charAt(a));
                }
                else if(array.charAt(a) == ')' || array.charAt(a) == ']' || array.charAt(a) == '}'){ // si el parentesis es de cierre 
                     evaluarParentesis.push(array.charAt(a));     
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultado; 
}
```

en si no fue muy difícil cubrir los casos mas obvios, como lo puede ser el inicio con un paréntesis cerrado, el final con uno abierto, y el caso de que tengan cantidad impar de paréntesis de un tipo u otro, en si mi problema principal es con lo siguientes casos:

1. "()[]{}"
2. "[({})]{}()"
3. "({(){}[]})[]"

El primero hasta cierto punto lo entiendo, se supone que se tiene que solucionar con una pila de tipo deque, así que un push y un pop serian suficientes, pero aun no se me ocurre como implementarlo para que funcione en conjunto con los otros casos. En cuanto al tema de los casos 2 y 3 directamente ni siquiera se como seria la lógica para verificarlos.

Agradecería una idea de lo que pudiese hacer.

**AVISO: EL CODIGO AUN NO LO HE PROBADO SOLO ESCRIBI LO QUE CREI QUE FUNCIONARIA EN BASE A LOGICA DE LAS DINTINTAS POSIBILIDADES, ASI QUE SI VEN ERRORES O COSAS QUE PUDIESE CORREGIR, TAMBIEN DIGANMELO PORFAVOR.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El primero hasta cierto punto lo entiendo, se supone que se tiene que
> solucionar con una pila de tipo deque, así que un push y un pop serian
> suficientes

Es correcto, con una pila se resuelven todas las combinaciones.

```
import java.util.Stack;
    
    public class Test {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            System.out.println(paridad("{[()()]}".toCharArray()));
    
        }
    
        public static boolean paridad(char[] cadena) {
    
            Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    
    
            for (char c : cadena) {
    
                // si son caracteres de apertura agregar a la pila
                if (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{')
                    stack.push(c);
                else {
                    // si son caracteres de cierre y la pila está vacía no hay 
                    // paridad
                    if (stack.isEmpty()) return false;
    
                    char caracter = stack.pop();
    
                    // si el caracter extraido de la pila no es el inverso del caracter
                    // actual del arreglo, no hay paridad
                    if (caracter != '(' && c == ')'
                            || caracter != '[' && c == ']'
                            || caracter != '{' && c == '}')
                        return false;
                }
    
            }
            // si la pila no queda vacía no hay paridad
            return stack.isEmpty();
        }
    }
```

Comment: aun me confunde un poco el como funciona, pero gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió de guia tu código.