# ¿Qué hago para que mi programa de paridad funcione?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo que hacer un programa para validar los parentecis "(","[","{".

Lo tengo que hacer con una pila.
Este el código de la clase Nodo

```
public class Nodo {

char letra;
Nodo siguiente;

public void Nodo() {
    this.siguiente = null;
}

public char getLetra() {
    return letra;
}

public void setLetra(char valor) {
    this.letra = valor;
}

public Nodo getSiguiente() {
    return siguiente;
}

public void setSiguiente(Nodo siguiente) {
    this.siguiente = siguiente;
}}
```

Cree una interfaz grafica sencilla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El botón tiene el siguiente evento:
Este es el evento que inserta los paréntesis a la pila.

```
private void btnVerificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int contador = 0;
    int contador1 = 0;

    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo();
    String cadena = this.txtCadena.getText();
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        nuevo.setLetra(cadena.charAt(i));
        if (cadena.charAt(i) == '(' || cadena.charAt(i) == '[' || cadena.charAt(i) == '{') {
            if (inicio == null) {
                inicio = nuevo;
                nuevo.setSiguiente(null);
            } else {
                nuevo.setSiguiente(inicio);
                inicio = nuevo;
            }
            System.out.println(cadena.charAt(i) + "\n");
            contador++;
        } else {
            if (cadena.charAt(i) == ')') {
                extraer();
                contador1++;
            } else if (cadena.charAt(i) == ']') {
                extraer();
                contador1++;

            } else if (cadena.charAt(i) == '}') {
                extraer();
                contador1++;

            }
        }
    }
    if (esVacia() == true) {
        System.out.println("Esta balanceada");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Esta balanceada");
    }
}
```

Hasta el momento la pila se esta llenando, pues se esta haciendo la insersión bien de los parentesis.
Tengo un error al momento de implementar el método de extraer.

```
public boolean extraer() {
    if (!esVacia()) {
        //Inicializa la lista agregando como inicio al nuevo nodo.
        inicio = inicio.getSiguiente();

        //Si no, va agragando los nodos al inicio de la lista
    }
    tamaño--;
    return true;
}
```

Que necesito hacer para poder hacer bien el programa... Que es lo que me falta...
Esto es lo que necesito:

- Ingresar una fórmula que contenga paréntesis, corchetes y llaves.
- Validar que los ( ) [] y {} estén correctamente balanceados.

Comment: Una cosa a la vez. Si dices que la pila tiene problemas en el método extraer  entonces deberías corregirlo antes de resolver lo de la paridad.

Comment: Por eso mi único problema es el método extraer.

Comment: Ya comprendo, pensé que tenías una clase Pila independiente, por eso te recomendé eso. Me gustaría sugerirte algo, implementa una Pila de forma independiente y no mezcles el código de la paridad con la lógica para manipular la pila. Te comparto un código de una Pila con sus tres métodos básicos: `pop, push y isEmpty` para que revises su estructura. https://gist.github.com/crrlos/ca309c246a389f369b2e158f132a5d97

Comment: Y la solución de la paridad usando una Pila está aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/399153/55132